# find dns lookup time from pcap

Tags: python, scapy

I have a `tcpdump` of a simple `HTTP Request to http://www.google.com`. Now, looking at the dump, I see that first a `dns request for google.com` is made which results in `a bunch of IPs` , then one of them is contacted via `HTTP`:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1 \r
```

Which returns a `301`. Again a `dns request for google.com` is made which results in a `bunch of IPS`, one of them is contacted via `HTTP` and the response is a `302` redirecting to `google.co.in`. Finally, a `dns request for google.co.in` is made and it gives me the final IP which will be used in the entire conversation.

I'm using `python` and `scapy`. I want to know the `total DNS lookup time` which is from the start of the `first dns request` to the end of `the last dns response`. How do I find the last successful dns response?

I can go through the packets one by one and look for `301` and `302` etc. but I was wondering if there's a more elegant way?

Comment: No, because the DNS requests are all successful (a query for an address returns an address) and independent.  DNS doesn't care whether you ask for the same name twice, a related name, or a totally different name - each request/response stands on its own.  The context that ties them together is the application making HTTP calls.  Your pcap analysis program will have to make a guess based on DNS IP addresses returned and IP addresses used in TCP/HTTP requests that they belong to the same app.  That works with only one app, but could get confusing if multiple apps contact Google simultaneously.